# Blue banner saying app is using location in background goes away after a few seconds when app closes

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

My app uses the users location when their utilizing the app. When they close the app to go home the blue banner saying '... is using your location' pops up. It goes away after a few seconds, but it's quite annoying and I don't think users will like it. How would I stop the location manager once the app closes? Not sure where to put that in the delegate, or how to even write it.

Added in a visual representation.

[image]

Comment: `CLLocationManager`'s `stopUpdatingLocation()` method?

Comment: @ILikeTau Right, but I'm at a loss at how to add that to the app delegate

Comment: Make your `CLLocationManger` a field, and access it in `applicationWillEnterBackground()`.

Comment: @ILikeTau this did not work unfortunately.

Comment: You probably have location access as background mode in your Info.plist. You should change it to when in use only.

Comment: @ILikeTau you're 100 percent right. I deleted app registers for location updates and it worked out. I'm assuming this won't have adverse effects on my app. As my locations update as normal.

Comment: @ILikeTau Add that as an answer so I can accept it. Points meng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have location access as background mode in your Info.plist. You should change it to when in use only.